# CSS content hexadecimal value getting trimmed when compiled

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I have a series of icons whose content is set from Kendo UI React, app is CRA. I'm trying to change the first icon by changing its `content`, as recommended.

```
  th.k-header[role=columnheader]:nth-child(1) .k-i-more-vertical:before {
   color: #ff0 !important;
   content: "\e030" !important;
}
```

However, when I inspect the element in a local environment, the unicode escape sequence has changed and is missing the initial backslash. It only shows up as a hexadecimal. (Formatted text and image):

```
.jITeNU th.k-header[role=columnheader]:nth-child(1) .k-i-more-vertical:before {
  color: #ff0 !important;
  content: "e030" !important;
}
```

[Chrome DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjclo.png)

When the content value is edited directly in dev tools (`content:  "\e030" !important`), the icon appears correctly.

Has anyone encountered this behavior before? I'm at a loss as to what is happening, since nothing else in the styles for that element has changed.

Comment: Try a space after the escaping backslash.

Comment: Sadly did not work - have also tried updating Chrome.

Comment: It might be a shot in the dark but have you tried escaping the backslash? `content: "\\e030" !important;`, sometimes webpack can have weird behaviours

Comment: It's not a problem in devtools (it just shows whatever you have), but a bug/mistake introduced by something in your react build/config/plugins. Try using the actual unicode character, which you can make in devtools console: `copy('\ue030')`

Comment: Do you use any css compiler/build tools? I tested it in Chrome 106. It works fine. See https://codepen.io/chybie/pen/oNdaObr

Comment: For this error - we are using a UI library with SCSS source files, so I think you're correct that this is a compiler error. I was (trying to) implement this styling via styled components in a JS file and was not using a CSS file. My colleague moved the styling to our `index.css` file and it worked as expected.